# plot categorization of strings, matlab

Tags: matlab

Edit: while the solution suggested works this format is problematic when I have many long strings, any suggestions?

Lets say I have categorized a vector of M stings into N groups. Meaning each of the M strings is assigned a number between 1 to N indicating the category the string belongs into. For example if M=6 and N=3 I might have:

```
v = [ 'a' ; 'b' ; 'c' ; 'd' ; 'e' ; 'f' ]
c = [  1  ;  2  ;  1  ;  1  '  3  ;  2  ]
```

which indicates that a, c and d were all categorized to group "1". "e" was categorized to group 3.

I want to somehow plot - using Matlab - this categorization.

I am trying something along the lines of:

```
plot(v,'b--o')
set(gca,'xticklabel',c.')
```

but I need the plot to look more like a scatter, sadly it seems scatter does not work with strings. Any suggestions?

Plus, the vector of strings might get very long, anyone knows how to make the plot scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

The following gets you a barchart with your names as x-axis labels. Uncomment the other line for  a scatterplot. In general, such a visualisation is probably not the right format for extremely many words (very high M).

```
v = [ 'a' ; 'b' ; 'c' ; 'd' ; 'e' ; 'f' ];
c = [  1  ;  2  ;  1  ;  1  ;  3  ;  2  ];

bar(c)
% scatter(1:length(c), c) % use this for a scatter plot
set(gca, 'xticklabel', v)
```

Comment: Yeh, this works, but as you said, this visualization did not work because of high number of long strings. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the purpose behind this? That might help with coming up with a suggestion.

Comment: I am trying to categorize parliament members into groups based on voting similarities, the strings are the names of the parliament members and the numbers are the groups a pattern recognition algorithm inferred.

Answer (score 1):

bar is usually slow. You can get a similar result more quickly and without Matlab binning things funnily by using plot.

Edit: I think you wanted the strings on the y axis.

```
plot(c,'bo')
ax = gca;
ax.XTick = 1:length(c);
ax.YTick = 0:max(c);
set(ax,'xticklabel',v)
view(-90,90)
```